# display data from mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

```
 document.write('<iframe  src=\"{<?php echo $row1['details']; ?>}\"</iframe>');
```

I'm trying to create an iFrame to be display using this javascript code, however when the code is executed, I can visually see the frame however, the frame is mirroring a 404 (Page Not found) error. Why's this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBN9v.png

Comment: Please specify your issue properly.

Comment: Provide us some more code

Comment: Where do u found  $row1 ?

This one is not found exactly make sure  $row1 found properly

Comment: @sayalok Pretty sure that it'd display a PHP error saying something like "Variable is undefined.".

Comment: hi  sayalok,  $row1 =mysqli_fetch_array>>>>>>$row1 its only variable???

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo $row1['details']; ?>` has got a ' while the outter function uses ' and ' to start and end its string. You'd have to do such as: `<?php echo $row1[\'details\']; ?>`. Next time please provide more code and describe your issue.

Also, you were missing a `>`.

```
document.write('<iframe  src=\"{<?php echo $row1[\'details\']; ?>}\"></iframe>');
```

Comment: its show erro >>>>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''details\']; ?>}\"></iframe>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\patty\cms.php on line 128   i try to put all code so may help>>>thx for respond

Comment: im trying to retrieve image source from mysql and display it through iframe using document.write

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="process_page" name="process_page" method="post" action="cms.php">
<select name="product" id="product"  onchange=prod(this.id)>
<option value="">------</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
</select>
</form>



 <?php 
$srv_vame="localhost";
$usr_name="root";
$pswrd="";
$udb="dt";
$sql_conn=mysqli_connect($srv_vame,$usr_name,$pswrd,$udb);

$f_ssql="select * from  category";
$fsql=mysqli_query($sql_conn,$f_ssql);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($fsql);
?>


<script type="text/javascript">

function prod(e)
{
var e=document.getElementById(e);
var AB =e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if(AB == 'A')
{
document.write('<iframe  src=\"{<?php echo $row1['details']; ?>}\"></iframe>');
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: If this is an answer can you please add some explenation? If this is extra information for your question you should use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48963338/edit) button below your question and include this information there. (And delete this answer when you are done in the last case)